# In Javascript is there a way to create an array of indexed objects with one statement?

Tags: javascript

I can create an array of objects like this:

```
var personType = []
personType[0] = "Plumber";
personType[1] = "Painter";
personType[4] = "Printer";
```

But is there a way I can do this with just one statement?

Comment: am, `var person = ["John", "Doe", 46]`??? and don't throw worlds like `object` in js thread :)

Comment: `var person = ["John", "Doe", 46];`

Comment: It doesn't really look like an array should be the structure here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: dystroy - Can you give me more advice about what you were saying. I wanted to create some kind of a look up mapping array as I have data coming from a server with a person type number that I wanted to convert to a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do

```
var person = ["John", "Doe", 46];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var person = ['John', 'Doe', 46];
```

But for that data I think you would be better off with an object:

```
var person = { fname: 'John', sname: 'Doe', age: 46 };
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added. Is there a way I can do this and specify index numbers that are not sequential?

Comment: The only way I can think to do that is add `null` to pad the array out: `var person = ['John', null, 'Doe', null, 46];`, for example.